# Fade each word of a slide in one by one

Tags: javascript, jquery, fadein

I have a function that fades each word in one by one. I'm trying to call this function instead of calling fadeIn for my slides but I'm at a lose as to where I would call the function to make this work.

I've created a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/d6r7gffs/

I want the slide to transition then fade each word in one by one, not transition fade in all the content then fade in each word one by one as it is currently functioning.

```
var $slider = $('.example ul'); // class or id of carousel slider
        var $slide = 'li'; // could also use 'img' if you're not using a ul
        var $transition_time = 1000; // 1 second
        var $time_between_slides = 8000; // 8 seconds

        function slides(){
            return $slider.find($slide);
        }

        slides().fadeOut();

        // set active classes
        slides().first().addClass('active');
        slides().first().fadeIn($transition_time, fadeWordsIn);


        // auto scroll 
        $interval = setInterval(function() {

            var $i = $slider.find($slide + '.active').index();

            slides().eq($i).removeClass('active');
            slides().eq($i).fadeOut($transition_time);

            if (slides().length == $i + 1) $i = -1; // loop to start

                slides().eq($i + 1).fadeIn($transition_time, fadeWordsIn);
                slides().eq($i + 1).addClass('active');

            }, $transition_time +  $time_between_slides

        );

        function fadeWordsIn() {
            var $el = $('.example ul li.active span'), text = $.trim($el.text()),
                words = text.split(" "), html = "";

            for (var i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
                html += "<span>" + words[i] + ((i+1) === words.length ? "" : " ") + "</span>";
            };
            $el.html(html).children().hide().each(function(i){
              $(this).delay(i*200).fadeIn(700);
            });
            $el.find("span").promise().done(function(){
                $el.text(function(i, text){
                   return $.trim(text);
                });            
            });
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

I updated the fiddle.  http://jsfiddle.net/d6r7gffs/5/ is automatic play and http://jsfiddle.net/d6r7gffs/4/ is wrapped in a function so you could restart the slider when it reaches the end.

I simplified the code a bit. Also, it really wasn't clear in your example what was a slide and what was a line.  The line's had `position:absolute;` so they would appear on top of each other (were these supposed to be the slides?).  Anyway, I gave the ul's the class `slide` so that it is clear what the elements in the example are supposed to be.  If this wasn't you intent, you should be able to understand how to modify it to your needs.

```
(function ($) {
    var linePause = 2000;
    var wordPause = 100;
    var slidePause = 8000;

    //this will execute on load to parse the words into spans
    $('.example ul.slide > li').each(function(){
        var words = $(this).html().split(' ');
        $(this).html('').hide();
        for(var i = 0; i < words.length; i++){
            $(this).append($('<span></span>')
                .text(words[i] + (i+1 == words.length ? '' : ' '))
                .hide());
        }
    });
    //this will run the animation on the created spans
    (function showNextSlide(slide){
        slide.eq(0).fadeIn(500, function(){
            (function showNextLine(line){   
                line.eq(0).fadeIn(500, function(){
                    (function showNextWord(word){
                        word.eq(0).fadeIn(wordPause, function(){
                            (word=word.slice(1)).length && showNextWord(word);
                        });
                    })(line.eq(0).find('span'));
                })
                .delay(linePause)
                .queue(function(){
                    (line=line.slice(1)).length && showNextLine(line);
                    $(this).dequeue();
                });
            })(slide.eq(0).find('li'));
        })
        .delay(slidePause)
        .fadeOut(500, function(){
            (slide=slide.slice(1)).length && showNextSlide(slide);
        });
    })($('.slide'))
})(jQuery);
```

Look at this like a nested for each loops (I know it's recursion but it models the same way):
for each slide in slider
  for each line on slide 
    for each word on line.

If you need additional clarification, let me know and I will be happy to help.

Comment: Hi Michael, thanks for responding. Your solution works onload but not for the slide transition.

Comment: I've updated the fiddle, it's working but I think this could be better. I moved the call to my function fadeWordsIn() under the addClass line in the loop, but I also needed to add .css('display', 'block'), otherwise both slides had style="display:none". http://jsfiddle.net/d6r7gffs/3/

Comment: I updated my answer.  This is the cleanest way I know...I'm sure someone else can do better.